# Instagram Basic Display API didn't approve our app but the implementation works, why?

Tags: instagram-api, instagram-graph-api

We're wanting to use Instagram Basic Display API, I implemented it, it works well. Basically what our app does with the API, is just getting the last 4 pictures of the user's instagram, and save it in our back-end, to later show it in the user's display case (a web app page where we show his information).

We tested it in our side, it workds, but when asking to Instagram for approval, it got refused and here's their message:

> Hello Team!
>
> While reviewing this submission, we were unable to verify the requested permissions because the use case details are invalid. We noticed that your use case details did not clearly explain or give guidance on how the permission was being used.
>
> The instagram_graph_user_profile permission allows your app to read the username of the IG account and provides a way to determine if the account is a professional.
>
> The allowed usage for this permission is to read fields in an Instagram user_profile (user's account type, user's ID, user's username).
>
> For the next submission, please provide us with a verifiable use case for the review team to test and verify the functionality of the requested permission.
>
> Here's a resource that may help:
>
> https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/overview#permissions

Do the UX matters when validating the app ?
Or are we doing so much little with the API ?

We tried to explain in details the step for our use case for approval, but nothing do.

Thanks in advance for your answers !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a long fight with Meta for getting our app approved, we finally did it !

Indeed, like Jojan said, we finally came across a reviewer that explained us why the app was not getting approved.

In our case, it was because we were ONLY using the API endpoints that is related to the "user_media" scope, and we never used the ones related to the "user_profile". But, to be approved for the "user_media" scope, we have first to be approved for the "user_profile" scope.

So to be approved, instead of only fetching the medias of the user, we also fetch the profile of the user and show it in a navbar.

I hope it'll help anyone !

Have a great day !

Comment: Confirming, a Facebook reviewer was able to approve the same violation in the same use case of my app only after querying [the User node](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/instagram-basic-display-api/guides/getting-profiles-and-media/#step-2--query-the-user-node) and placing a result of this call somewhere on my site. This requires sending them a screencast approving the outputting of the requested information.

Answer (score 1):

We are also in the process of getting our app reviewed for Instagram.

So far we have been rejected 10 times over the last 3 weeks. They reject us because we did not provide test accounts, then they rejected us because we provided test accounts. (yes seriously). We get rejected on the use case once in a while (the use case does not change). Still, sometimes it's ok, then it's not. We had the reviewer download the app from the App Store instead of testing the provided builds. Guess what, the new feature for which I don't have permission to use is not in my production builds, go figure. etc etc etc

What I've read from other victims is that you keep submitting and hope you get a reviewer who is willing to actually read what you put in your notes.

Also praying helps.